# Cannot convert return expression of type 'EventLoopFuture<String>' to return type 'String'

Tags: ios, swift, vapor

I have this error in my Vapor project:

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'EventLoopFuture<String> ' to return type 'String'

```swift
app.get("user", ":uuid") { req throws -> EventLoopFuture<String> in
        let uuid = req.parameters.get("uuid") ?? ""
        return User.query(on: req.db).filter(\.$uuid == uuid).first().flatMapThrowing { user in
            if let user = user {
                // return a string value
                return try Response(data: ["user": user.makeDictionary()])
            }else {
                // not found, return all users
                // problem is: Cannot convert return expression of type 'EventLoopFuture<String>' to return type 'String'
                return User.query(on: req.db).all().map { $0.map { $0.makeDictionary() } }.flatMapThrowing { dicArray in
                    return try Response(data: ["users": dicArray])
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Have you tried to replace `EventLoopFuture<String>` with `EventLoopFuture<Response>`?

Comment: I just try it. But cann't resolve it. New error: Cannot convert return expression of type 'String' to return type 'Response', Cannot convert return expression of type 'EventLoopFuture<String>' to return type 'Response'

Comment: You just have to read that old good article about EventLoopFutures https://kirilltitov.com/en/blog/2019/futures

Answer (score 3):

You just declared that you will return String in the future, while you're trying to return Response. And also you have to replace `flatMapThrowing` with `tryFlatMap`.

Fixed code

```swift
app.get("user", ":uuid") { req throws -> EventLoopFuture<Response> in
    let uuid = req.parameters.get("uuid") ?? ""
    return User
        .query(on: req.db)
        .filter(\.$uuid == uuid)
        .first()
        // here you can't use flatMapThrowing
        // cause it doesn't support EventLoopFuture result
        .tryFlatMap { user -> EventLoopFuture<Response> in
            if let user = user {
                // here you wrap simple return with future
                // cause it is needed for tryFlatMap
                let response = try Response(data: ["user": user.makeDictionary()])
                return req.eventLoop.makeSucceededFuture(response)
            } else {
                // here you return future with User
                return User.query(on: req.db).all()
                    // then you transform it to future with dictionary
                    .map { $0.map { $0.makeDictionary() } }
                    // then you transform it to future with Response
                    .flatMapThrowing { dicArray in
                        return try Response(data: ["users": dicArray])
                    }
            }
        }
}
```